# How i can pull a map using interface builder

Tags: interface-builder, mkmapview

I am trying to pull the map through interface builder in my application, Someone please help me with this and pleas tell me clearly step by step what i need to do. 
I am really new to these things, I will really appreciate your concern.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All others who have same problem should need to add MapKit framework. You can do this by ctrl+click on Frameworks then Add existing and browse to MapKit framework.

Thanks,